# Curl not working as expected

Tags: php, curl

in this code :

```
$url  = 'http://example.com/someLARGE.file';
    $path = 'test.txt';

    $fp = fopen($path, 'w+');

    $curl = curl_init();

    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    fclose($fp);
```

The output is written to the browser and not to the file on the server :(

Comment: can you confirm that you can write to $path - curl does not always report errors on invalid file handles

Comment: @jrowley , can u post a question so i can accept it ?

Comment: if you figured out the solution write an answer yourself and then accept it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in
    $fp = fopen($path, 'w+');
I did not have permissions to create/write to the file .

Answer (score 1):

try with [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
$result = curl_exec($curl);

file_put_contents($file, $result,FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

`file_put_contents` is identical to calling `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()`
successively to write data to a file.

Comment: This will only work if you uncomment the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER line